# await aiohttp.request не работает python 3

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, aiohttp

Решил научится асинхронному программированию 
Столкнулся с такой ошибкой уже не раз, не могу понять в чём дело

```
File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/untitled/main.py", line 32, in fetch_async
    response = await aiohttp.request('GET', URL) 
TypeError: object _SessionRequestContextManager can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Код программы такой

```
import time
import asyncio
import aiohttp

URL = 'https://api.github.com/events'
MAX_CLIENTS = 1
async def fetch_async(pid):
    print('Fetch async process {} started'.format(pid))
    start = time.time()
    response = await aiohttp.request('GET', URL)
    datetime = response.headers.get('Date')

    print('Process {}: {}, took: {:.2f} seconds'.format(
        pid, datetime, time.time() - start))
    response.close()
    return datetime


async def asynchronous():
    start = time.time()
    tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(
        fetch_async(i)) for i in range(1, MAX_CLIENTS + 1)]
    await asyncio.wait(tasks)
    print("Process took: {:.2f} seconds".format(time.time() - start))

ioloop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
ioloop.run_until_complete(asynchronous())
ioloop.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел такое решение

```
    async with aiohttp.request('GET', URL) as response:
    datetime = response.headers.get('Date')

    response.close()
    return 'Process {}: {}, took: {:.2f} seconds'.format(
        pid, datetime, time.time() - start)
```

Но ответа на вопрос почему это работает так в то время как на многих сайтах пишут что это нужно использовать так `response = await aiohttp.request('GET', URL)`  мне найти не удалось

Comment: Видимо, в новой версии функция `aiohttp.request` возвращает не сопрограмму, а асинхронный контекстный менеджер.